# Email data extension date daily, how?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions, automationstudio

If I want to receive data from a data extension on daily basis, how can I do that?

By data I mean all data. It can be in an email body or attached excel file as a report.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Automation Studio. The workflow of your *scheduled automation* will basically look like this:

**Data Extract Activity -> File Transfer Activity -> Send Email Activity**

The Data Extract activity reads data from your data extension and writes it to a file in the *Export*-folder of your Marketing Cloud's enhanced FTP. The File Transfer activity needs to be configured to move the file to the *Import*-folder, so it can be used by the Send Email activity, that needs to send an email using the `AttachFile(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`-AMPscript function to attach the file.

**Further reading:**

- [AttachFile](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/attachfile2/#AttachFile)
- [Automation Studio documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/)

Comment: In this case, what will be the AMPScript to attach file from Import folder? `%%=AttachFile("FTP","Import",true,"MyData.xlsx")=%%`

Comment: The documentation is very clear about this and even presents an example for attaching a file from the Import-folder. However it depends on how you name the file in your extract activity and how you want the file to be named in the email itself: `%%=AttachFile("FTP", "nameSpecifiedInExtractActivity.xls", "anyNameYouLikeInYourEmail.xls")=%%`

Comment: I am using this exact ampscript but the email is coming as text..no attachment. 
`%=AttachFile("FTP", "Daily_File.csv", "DailyFile_NewName.csv")=%%`

Comment: I meant `%%=AttachFile("FTP", "Daily_File.csv", "DailyFile_NewName.csv")=%%` I see the in tracking that this email is throwing ERROR

Comment: It seems like csv isn't a supported filetype which is strange as this is the default format created by marketing cloud... In this case a conversion needs to be done or you really need to put it into the body of the message (which could be unpractical if your data extension contains a lot of data).

Comment: Is PDF a supported format? I also created a new topic for advice on how to dislpay DE rows in email (I only have 100 rows)....fyi https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175879/can-i-display-de-data-all-rows-in-an-email

Comment: I just tested PDF..the tracking section is still throwing an error on email sent. The file is 3-4MB..not sure if it is a size issue. As per the documentation, PDF and zip both are supported formats and i tired both..

Comment: A PDF definitely is supported! Could you please use the email validation tools to check what's wrong with the email? Is the file in the Import directory? Maybe you didn't include the necessary data (physical mailing address, etc.) in the email?

Comment: Thank you Markus for all your help. I will investigate into that issue. For the time being, I am displaying data in the email body from the data extension.