# Automate a Data Extension export and send via email

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions, automationstudio

I have a team that does not have access to SFMC needing to view a DE within SFMC on a regular basis. Is there a way to automate an export of this DE on a daily basis and send to that team via email (in csv format)?

Or is the only way to do this via a Data Extract to FTP? (They do not have access to the FTP either...)

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this are welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email data extension date daily, how?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175854/email-data-extension-date-daily-how)

Comment: Likely your best bet would be to have it rolled out inside the email or on a landing page via scripting pulling from that data extension (no need to export) as the AttachFile solution runs into 2 issues. 1. It has a cost associated per send. 2. I do not believe it supports CSV files (at least it did not last time I checked).

Comment: I think with the landing page there could be security issues, as if someone outside the orgnization has access to the landing page link they can also view the data.